# In ASP.NET MVC how to refactor try/catch and return JSON error message?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, error-handling, refactoring

How best to create a base controller in a new ASP.NET MVC application that will contain boilerplate code to handle all try/catch routines for every action in derived controllers and return a standard JSON error message after logging to Nlog. I would also like to handle 404 errors to redirect to a custom 404 view. I aim using OWIN cookie authentication and would like to signout when the cookie expires. All my actions will be returning JsonResult and invoked via jQuery Ajax.

In previous projects I've used the following approach:

In `Global.asax.cs`

```
  protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception lastError = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();

        var statusCode = 0;

        statusCode = lastError.GetType() == typeof(HttpException) ? ((HttpException)lastError).GetHttpCode() : 500;

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", statusCode);
        routeData.Values.Add("exception", lastError);

        if (new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request).IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Ajax");     
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
        }

        var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);

        IController controller = new ErrorController();
        controller.Execute(requestContext);

        Response.End();
    }
```

In `ErrorController.cs`

```
 public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int statusCode, Exception exception)
    {
        var model = new ErrorModel { HttpStatusCode = statusCode, Exception = exception.Message };

        Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

        return View(model);
    }

    public JsonResult Ajax(int statusCode, Exception exception, Dictionary<string,string> validationErrors = null)
    {
        var model = new ErrorModel { HttpStatusCode = statusCode, Exception = exception.Message };

        if (exception.GetType() == typeof (DbEntityValidationException))
        {
            model.ValidationErrors = null;
        }
        else
        {
            model.ValidationErrors = validationErrors;
        }

        Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing that is by extending the `HandleErrorAttribute` like this:

```
public class AjaxAwareHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Execute the normal exception handling routine...
        base.OnException(filterContext);            

        // Verify if AJAX request...
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // Use Json in case of AJAX request...
            var result = new JsonResult();                
            result.Data = new { Error = filterContext.Exception.Message };

            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, all you need to do is to register that attribute in your `FilterConfig` class under the `App_Start` folder like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AjaxAwareHandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```